# 'password_hash() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given' when project uploaded to server

Tags: php

I encryp the pass like this:

```
$Clave=password_hash($_POST["txtClave"], PASSWORD_ARGON2I);
```

And it works on my PC. But, when I uploaded the project to a server the error_log file shows:

> password_hash() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given

Why is that? How can I fix this?

**Edit**

I ran a phpInfo file on server and it turned out server version of PHP is 7.1.26 even though on phpMyAdmin it says is 7.2.7

So what would be the best option to ecrypt the password now?

Comment: what php version are you using?

Comment: @kuh-chan 7.2.14

Comment: Has PHP on the server been compiled with Argon2 support?

Comment: @jeroen so the problem is that the server has an inferior php version, isn't it?

Comment: Change PASSWORD_ARGON2I to PASSWORD_DEFAULT. you maybe don't have the Argon2 support...

Comment: @ErrolChavesMoya You have the correct version for `ARGON2I`.

Comment: `print PHP_VERSION;` or `phpinfo()` to verify your assumption about the running PHP version. Additionally enable notices in `error_reporting`, because this should have gotten you one.

Comment: @mario server php version is  7.2.7

Comment: @jeroen on my PC I am using PHP v. 7.2.14 in server is v. 7.2.7

Comment: Then one of the build flags is possibly `—without-password-argon2`. Or you still haven't checked phpinfo().

Comment: @mario on server you mean, right?